# Add a list in a python object if key value is the same

Tags: python

I have a json file with different objectID and a list of results in each object. I want to keep only one object with the same id and add the results of the other on one.
The question is how to merge/concatenate (?) objects with the same ID to have only on but with all the results (list in my example) ?
My input:

```
[{
    'objectID': 10745,
    'date': 'april 2020',
    'results': [{
        'model': 'AUDI - TT QUATTRO',
        'price_str': '4 800 EUR'
    }]
}, {
    'objectID': 10745,
    'results': [{
        'model': 'Porsche 911',
        'price_str': '48 000 EUR'
    }]
}]
```

The expected output:

```
[{
    'objectID': 10745,
    'results': [{
        'model': 'AUDI - TT QUATTRO',
        'price_str': '4 800 EUR'
    },
  {
        'model': 'Porsche 911',
        'price_str': '48 000 EUR'
    }]
}]
```

My code:

```
for item in data:
    objectId = item["objectID"]
    results = item["results"]

    def removeDuplicate():
        new_results = [d for i, d in enumerate(data) if d['objectID'] not in set(
            map(lambda x:x['objectID'], data[:i])) or d['results']]
        data[:] = new_results
    removeDuplicate()
```

In reality it can be 5 same objects with the same `objectID`, not just one, but it's for the example

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Are you looking for help with your code?

Comment: The question is how to merge/concatenate (?) objects with the same ID to have only on but with all the results (list in my example) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I could think of at the moment would be to manipulate a dictionary, since we can search with a unique key (in this case, objectID).  If the key doesn't exist, then we haven't found an object with this objectID and we can safely insert it at that key.  Otherwise, we append the results of the newly-found item to the one already at that key.  Then we just take the list of the values of the dict, since that would remove any trace of the objectID as a key.

```py
data = [{
    'objectID': 10745,
    'date': 'april 2020',
    'results': [{
        'model': 'AUDI - TT QUATTRO',
        'price_str': '4 800 EUR'
    }]
}, {
    'objectID': 10745,
    'results': [{
        'model': 'Porsche 911',
        'price_str': '48 000 EUR'
    }]
}]

new_data = {}
for item in data:
    if item['objectID'] in new_data:
        new_data[item['objectID']]['results'] += item['results']
    else:
        new_data[item['objectID']] = {'objectID' : item['objectID'], 'results' : item['results']}

print(list(new_data.values()))
```

If there's a faster or more elegant solution, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

You could user a temporary default dict. This will require 1 pass over your input arr to create the intermediate dict. Another pass over dict to create output list.

```
>>> input_arr=[{
...     'objectID': 10745,
...     'date': 'april 2020',
...     'results': [{
...         'model': 'AUDI - TT QUATTRO',
...         'price_str': '4 800 EUR'
...     }]
... }, {
...     'objectID': 10745,
...     'results': [{
...         'model': 'Porsche 911',
...         'price_str': '48 000 EUR'
...     }]
... }]
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict as dd
>>> temp_dict=dd(list)
>>> for d in input_arr:
...  temp_dict[d['objectID']].extend(d['results'])
... 
>>> temp_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {10745: [{'model': 'AUDI - TT QUATTRO', 'price_str': '4 800 EUR'}, {'model': 'Porsche 911', 'price_str': '48 000 EUR'}]})
>>> out_arr=[]
>>> for k,v in temp_dict.items():
...  out_arr.append({'objectID':k, 'results':v})
... 
>>> out_arr
[{'objectID': 10745, 'results': [{'model': 'AUDI - TT QUATTRO', 'price_str': '4 800 EUR'}, {'model': 'Porsche 911', 'price_str': '48 000 EUR'}]}]
```